# php mail function and mail server

Tags: php, email

With php mail http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php if the mail is sent ok it returns true.

But with my web host the sent rate is 3000/hour and the server will then store 450 e-mails after the 3000 limit has been reached (which is 15% of the 3000 limit).

What I would like confirmation of is that when the php mail function returns true is it coping with these settings. Does the mail server confirm to the mail function that it sent OK or is the mail function 'blind' to that?

Does the mail server say to the function, limit reached email not sent so return false?

Comment: dont use mail() for mass mailing, even says so on the mail page. **"It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient. **

Comment: unlikely the mail is being queued up for you by the host. more likely it chucks them out. only the host can confirm this. be careful sending large amounts of email especially from a shared host, especially if you don't know what you are doing :-)

Comment: The mail function only returns true if it's accepted for delivery, but it has no idea what happens after that. Like the docs state, "It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `mail()` function that comes with PHP is not an optimal solution. Use SWIFTMAILER http://swiftmailer.org/ This will use as SMTP service:

Example of code when using swiftmailer as SMTP service:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password')
  ;

/*
You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

// Sendmail
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Mail
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
*/

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```